# how to make cells independent with each other in notebook

Tags: notebooks, documentation, contexts, cells

If we open `DocumentationCenter` and then run code, we will find that the `Cells` are independent from each other.

For example:

[image]

- `a` or `b` in third `Cell` is  independent from the one in the first or second `Cell`.

I think maybe it is local cell?

If I want to achieve this behaviour in my notebook, how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not each `Cell` but each `CellGroup` has separate context. If you create new cell you will get `In[2]`:

> [image]

You can confirm this thesis with:

```
nb = Select[Notebooks[], "Help" === ("DocumentType" /. NotebookInformation[#]) &][[1]]

Options[#, CellContext] & /@ Cells[nb, GeneratedCell -> False, CellStyle -> "Input"]
```

> ```
> {{CellContext -> CellGroup}, <<18>>, {CellContext -> CellGroup}}
> ```

So it is an `Option` that you can fix, e.g. via menu:

> [image]